# Chart.js 2 - Axis Layer Padding

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to get labels drawn on top of a line chart using Chart.js

I found the option `options.scales.xAxes.gridLines.tickMarkLength` but it seems like the graph is rendered on top of it:

[image: chart]

Perhaps I'm using it wrong. Is there any other method to render x and y labels within the chart?

Comment: do you mean you want the x-axis displayed at the top of the chart or do you want each point in the graph to have it's label displayed above it?

Comment: I want the labels to be displayed on top of the chart. It seems the chart is rendered above. Sorry for not being clear (the label content in the picture is irrelevant, I left some of them empty on purpose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, you can do it using 

`ticks: {
  mirror: true
}`

Read more about it here http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#ticks-configuration